# How to immediately shuffle numbers from the results of an API call?

Tags: javascript, shuffle

This is definitely a beginner problem, but I can’t figure it out or find an answer anywhere, so I’m hoping someone here can tell me what I’m doing wrong without too much bother. I'm making a call to an API, getting a series of ID numbers corresponding to categories back that I'm putting into an array. I want to then shuffle the numbers in that array so I can use the ID numbers in a random order easily later on. When I run this code I get an error that the return statement at the end is an illegal return statement. If I run it without the stuff with the counter and my attempt at shuffling, there's no error.

```
async function getCategoryIds() {
    let idArray = [];
    let fullCatInfoArray = [];
    let response = await axios.get('API URL');

    for (let cats of response.data) {
        idArray.push(cats.id);
    }

    let counter = idArray.length;

    while (counter > 0) {
      let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
    
      counter--;
    
      let temp = idArray[counter];
      idArray[counter] = idArray[index]; 
      idArray[index] = temp; 
    }    
  
    return idArray;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more context ? I ran your code on codesandbox and its working fine ->
https://codesandbox.io/s/node-playground-forked-35qn5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @hanut You know, one of the things I'm finding learning this stuff is that I can work on something that isn't working until my eyes glass over, and then I do some small thing I might not even notice, and then when I ask about it, the person tells me it's working fine, and I have a look and it turns out they were right. Sorry and thank you. Should I delete this question?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to apologize. I'm glad to help. I've learned from the platform just as you will too. Keep at it, its going to get a lot easier.
That said, an upvote on the comment wouldn't hurt